# match and replace from pattern

Tags: python, r, replace, match

Sorry will keep rules in mind. says previous post is deleted, so i had to do another. 
Two character columns in two data frames xa and ya. xa is more perfect than ya, so would like to match those in ya to those in xa,  but return the match in xa.

this is what i have, but it it is much more longer and it is not a line by line matching

```
xa = c("boxes","card","picture","combs".....)
ya= c("comb","paste","crda","boes"......)
```

This is what I did in R

```
fibon <- 
for (i in ya)
sapply(xa, function(x) { if (
agrepl(ya, x, max.distance=0.1)==TRUE)
fibon <- as.list(return(i))})
```

This appear to run but never ends
I did think about using index and I have tried using the agrep indices component too

```
fibon <- 
sapply(xa, function(x)
m <- agrep(ya, x, max.distance=0.1, value=F) 
fibon <- replace (x, m, ya[m]))
```

but it returns matches from xa not from ya

Thanks

Edit
Another way to look at it is to say :
ya could be a lookup table and I want to replace every approximately matched element in xa with its match in ya, the lookup table

Comment: Do ya differ from xa at random or is there a pattern? Like all letters from ya are present xa?

Comment: Thx. the content of xa or ya differ at random, as in the position where they match is not set, anyone in xa could have an approximate match in any position in ya, ya is even longer really.    Second, u mean if content match exactly? I am using agrep and calling max.distance because letters won't match exactly,

Comment: Have a look at minhash and locality-sensitive hashing in general. Also, the David Robinson's fuzzyjoin package could be of use.

Comment: Thanks @deann, my understanding of fuzzyjoin was that it merges matches with same position  in columns, it would not look down for matches.  Thx I will examine these